# Unable to open a file for writing

Tags: php, file, file-io, filesystems

I am trying to write to a file. I do a `file_exists` check on it before I do `fopen` and it returns `true` (the file does exist).

However, the file fails this code and gives me the error every time:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
if($handle)
{
    flock($handle, LOCK_EX);
    fwrite($handle, $contents);
}
else
{
    echo 'ERROR: Unable to open the file for writing.',PHP_EOL;
    exit();
}
flock($handle, LOCK_UN);
fclose($handle);
```

Is there a way I can get more specific error details as to why this file does not let me open it for writing? I know that the filename is legit, but for some reason it just wont let me write to it. I do have write permissions, I was able to write and write over another file.

Comment: file existence has nothing to do with writing to this file. you can write to unexisted file as well. it will be just created. There is  some other cause, can be revealed by error message.

Comment: Note about `file_exists()` - it checks both files and directories; PHP also has `is_file()` for files and `is_dir()` for directories.

Answer (score 2):

Just because the file exists doesn't mean that you have permission to write to it.  Before trying to write to a file, you should check to see if PHP has permission to do so using [`is_writable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using php 5.2+ you might be interested in [error_get_last()](http://de.php.net/error_get_last).
On your development system you can also increase the error reporting level, either within the script via [error_reporting()](http://php.net/error_reporting) or (preferably) in your php.ini.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
if(!$handle) {
  echo 'ERROR: Unable to open the file for writing.',PHP_EOL;
  var_dump(error_get_last());
  exit();
}

flock($handle, LOCK_EX);
fwrite($handle, $contents);
flock($handle, LOCK_UN);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `E_ALL | E_STRICT` (or `-1`? not sure) as error reporting level.

Answer (score 1):

or general way of getting errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); // for the development PC only
error_reporting(E_ALL); // ALWAYS
```

to see the actual error message

Comment: or even more generic way: `ini_set('display-errors', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === '127.0.0.1');` (always), where 127.0.0.1 is developer's IP ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the directory you're writing to doesn't have the correct permissions.